# One-time-passwords with mediawiki AuthPlugin

Tags: php, authentication, mediawiki, one-time-password

I have created an AuthPlugin extension to do SecurID one-time-password authentication. So far, so good. I can authenticate and create users when the first log in. However, the first login always authenticates twice. It authenticates the first time to create the user and a second time to actually log them in. You may see the problem here: the one-time-password is used the first time, so the user is not logged in. Subsequent logins work fine.

I've traced the first auth calls to `/includes/specials/SpecialUserlogin.php` (and I'm not sure which one is being called, but I could find the offending one and remove it):

```
<?php
/**
 * Make a new user account using the loaded data.
 * @private
 * @throws PermissionsError|ReadOnlyError
 * @return Status
 */
public function addNewAccountInternal() {
    // ...snip...
    // If we are not allowing users to login locally, we should be checking
    // to see if the user is actually able to authenticate to the authenti-
    // cation server before they create an account (otherwise, they can
    // create a local account and login as any domain user). We only need
    // to check this for domains that aren't local.
    if ( 'local' != $this->mDomain && $this->mDomain != '' ) {
        if (
            !$wgAuth->canCreateAccounts() &&
            (
                !$wgAuth->userExists( $this->mUsername ) ||
                !$wgAuth->authenticate( $this->mUsername, $this->mPassword )
            )
        ) {
            return Status::newFatal( 'wrongpassword' );
        }
    }

//...snip...
/**
 * Attempt to automatically create a user on login. Only succeeds if there
 * is an external authentication method which allows it.
 *
 * @param $user User
 *
 * @return integer Status code
 */
function attemptAutoCreate( $user ) {
   // ...snip...
    if ( !$wgAuth->authenticate( $user->getName(), $this->mPassword ) ) {
        wfDebug( __METHOD__ . ": \$wgAuth->authenticate() returned false, aborting\n" );

        return self::WRONG_PLUGIN_PASS;
    }
```

So, if all users need to authenticate with the one-time-password system (if I prevent logins from local accounts and local account creation), is there a problem removing the offending `authenticate` calls? Am I being terribly insecure here? Or is there a better way to do this? Should I be doing something other than extending the `AuthPlugin`? For example, I override these `AuthPlugin` methods:

```
<?php
/**
 * Return true to prevent logins that don't authenticate here from being
 * checked against the local database's password fields.
 *
 * This is just a question, and shouldn't perform any actions.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function strict() {
    return true;
}

/**
 * Check if a user should authenticate locally if the global authentication fails.
 * If either this or strict() returns true, local authentication is not used.
 *
 * @param string $username Username.
 * @return bool
 */
public function strictUserAuth( $username ) {
    return true;
}
```

I would like to avoid pre-creating all the users and keeping them sync'd, but that would be one way to avoid the initial duplicate auth calls.

BTW, I think the real authenticate call for the session happens in `includes/User.php`:

```
<?php
public function checkPassword( $password ) {
    global $wgAuth, $wgLegacyEncoding;
    $this->load();

    // Certain authentication plugins do NOT want to save
    // domain passwords in a mysql database, so we should
    // check this (in case $wgAuth->strict() is false).

    if ( $wgAuth->authenticate( $this->getName(), $password ) ) {
        return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use the same way as the [TwoFactorAuthentication](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TwoFactorAuthentication) extension used on wikitech.wikimedia.org.

You can use the [`AbortLogin`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/AbortLogin) Hook to check your one time password, before the user data is checked. The problem: You have to make sure, that the one time password is only marked as "used", when the user logged in succesfully.

(I hope you don't want to replace the "normal" user password with "only" a one time passwort).

Comment: I like your answer, but it isn't really two-factor... it's only one one-time-password with no static password. So, there's no static password to auth with (unless I'm missing something here).

Comment: Argh, i think i have missunderstood your question a little bit :) To avoid the first call of authenticate it should be enugh to implement getDomain() in your AuthPlugin and return only `'local'`.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll check that out and see what I find out.